# Broken Age, with Shay "breaking out"

Tags: broken-age

Hello I just purchased Broken Age and I've really enjoyed it so far but I've come across a glitch and I can't work past it. I'm currently trying to put the omicron inhibitor on the fusion orb in the breaking out part of the game with shay but the game won't let me actually put it on! At first I thought maybe I was doing something wrong but after I eventually looked at some internet cheats I realized it was the game itself that isn't working. Shay just keeps saying that it's meant to go on the fusion orb (which is what I'm doing!) please advise, I would love to be able to finish this game!

Answer (score 1):

Try placing the inhibitor higher than the fusion orb artwork.  There is a glitch where the artwork is actually below where the fusion orb is coded to be